# Can't connect to local rinkeby node from web3.js

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, truffle

I'm developing a Dapp using truffle and I need to connect to a contract that I uploaded on rinkeby using `truffle migrate --network rinkeby`. Problem is that I'm unable to connect to the rinkeby network from the web3 interface. I run a rinkeby local node using

```
geth --rinkeby --rpc --rpcapi db,eth,net,web3,personal --rpcport 8545 --rpcaddr localhost --rpccorsdomain "*" --unlock="0x4A1b47b0b119AFD421ec4E3b5B54D8EF5141b59c"
```

The front-end code is

```
if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined'){
        web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
    }else{
        web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));
  }
```

But the code always slaps me with

```
Error: Provider not set or invalid.
```

How can I resolve this issue and how to create a new contract instance from contract abi?

Comment: have you tried `--rpcaddr 0.0.0.0`? this has worked for me in the past though I can't remember why, hence the comment instead of a full answer!

Comment: Have you set the provider in the truffle.js file? If not here is the code `rinkeby: {
        host: "localhost",
        port: 8545,
        network_id: 4,
        from: "address", 
        gas: gas
    }`

Answer (score 0):

Dapp using truffle and local server this commend run:

```
geth --rinkeby --rpc --rpcapi db,eth,net,web3,personal --rpcport 8545 --rpcaddr "http://localhost:8000" --rpccorsdomain "*" --unlock="0x4A1b47b0b119AFD421ec4E3b5B54D8EF5141b59c"
```

and try it http://localhost:8000

Rpc domain --rpc --rpccorsdomain "http://localhost:8000" then run project

Comment: It is not working either.

Comment: I tried this `geth --rinkeby --rpc --rpcapi db,eth,net,web3,personal --rpcport 8545 --rpcaddr localhost --rpccorsdomain "http://localhost:8000" --unlock="0x4A1b47b0b119AFD421ec4E3b5B54D8EF5141b59c"`. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: geth --networkid 20 --port 60303 --rpc  --rpccorsdomain "http://localhost:8000" --lightkdf --cache 16 --datadir "D:\Database\final_chain_database" console     this commend run and  genesis file inti then this commend run then "npm start "

Comment: The problem persists. I would like to hear what is going wrong here, then explain to me how I can fix the problem.

Comment: What version of web3? 95% of the issues I've been having recently are due to the breaking changes between v0.x and v1.0(which is now installed by default). If your web3 version is v1.x try switching to v0.20.x or v0.19.x. The way you have the front end code the v1 will most likely fail (trust me, been a month long headache haha)

Comment: yes this problem issue but i am try and this code working .thanks heheh  ryanh